# CGO build failing due to missing system libraries

Tags: go, gcc, linker, llvm, cgo

I have a fairly simple issue: I am using CGO w/ GCC to build a project that depends on a package that binds to C (llvm-go).  As a result of this, there are several libraries that this library needs to build that appear to be default Windows system libraries.  Here is the error output:

```
gcc.exe: error: psapi.lib: No such file or directory
gcc.exe: error: shell32.lib: No such file or directory
gcc.exe: error: ole32.lib: No such file or directory
gcc.exe: error: uuid.lib: No such file or directory
gcc.exe: error: advapi32.lib: No such file or directory
gcc.exe: error: z.lib: No such file or directory
gcc.exe: error: libxml2.lib: No such file or directory
```

LLVM provides a tool that generates the link and include options for CGO for me.  They are fairly numerous so pasting them here would be unwise.

I am using TDM GCC for Windows 10 with Go 1.16.

I don't know if there is an additional linker flag I need to add/remove to fix this issue.  Let me know if you need any additional information.  Thanks!

Comment: The libraries listed are part of the Windows SDK so minimally you'll need to install that

Comment: It is installed as far as I know -- under `WindowsKits` in `Program Files (x86)`.